# Command to get Files with last access date in windows

Tags: windows

I have a file server (Windows 2003). I want to get a list of files and folders inside each drive, with their last access dates.
I know, there are tools like treesize, but due to some reasons, I can not use them on this server.

Is there any command to get this list?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `cmd` command:

```
dir /s /ta
```

You can redirect the output to a file if you need to manipulate it with Windows programs.

Answer (score 3):

open a powershell window and you can do this, and even sort on lastaccesstime. you can look up the command get-childitem and do more things with it.

```
gci -recurse . | select name,lastaccesstime,psparentpath |sort lastaccesstime
```

Comment: note that updating the access time must be enabled: https://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7