# Viewing the date a file was last opened from a shared folder on a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, filesystems

Suppose you have an application on a Windows XP PC that is accessing jpeg files from a share folder on a Windows 7 PC.  I need to see which of those files have been opened recently, and I would prefer not to edit registry settings to enable 'NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate' as described here: [The last access date is not changed even after reading the file on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7)

Would checking the 'Recent Items' folder for lnk files in Windows 7 work - even though it is being opened from the XP machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, right-click on the header (where "Name", "Size" etc. are displayed) and select *More...* and add the column "Date accessed". You can sort and search on that field.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows file auditing can record every time someone opens (or attempts to open) any file that has auditing configured. It saves date+time, username, and access type, in a record in the Windows log. I've never used it. (There are probably tools to make viewing audit information easier.)